# Solving the equation $ex - xe^{5x-1} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ex - xe^{5x-1} = 0$$

$$e \cdot x + e^{5x} \cdot e^{-1} \cdot x = 0$$

$$e^{5x} + 1 \cdot x^2 = 0$$

And then i dont know what to do.

Comment: Double-check your last equation, it is currently wrong.

Comment: ... it is still wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

$$ex-xe^{5x-1}=0\\
x(e-e^{5x-1})=0\to x=0 \text{ or }e=e^{5x-1}$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$, you clearly have $ex-xe^{5x-1}=0$. And if $x\ne0$, you can divide by $x$, getting $e-e^{5x-1}=0$. And\begin{align}e-e^{5x-1}=0&\iff e=e^{5x-1}\\&\iff1=5x-1\\&\iff x=\frac25.\end{align}